# Nginx upstream server works with IP address but not with DNS

Tags: docker, nginx, dns, request, nginx-reverse-proxy

Sorry for mistakes. I am new with Nginx.

I have my application deployed on docker engine.
So I have basically 5 docker images but here 2 are most important:

- 1st backend.   (Django DRF application using gunicorn)
- 2nd frontend.  (React App on Nginx)

I am upstreaming backend on Nginx so in Nginx.conf file I have 2 locations defined:

1. "/" for frontend
2. "/api" for backend (upstream backend to be able to use it).

I am able to start my containers and they "talk" to each other if I am using IP address in my browser. So backend get requests and give responses.

Now I bought dns and added ssl certificates (LetsEncrypt, but still i have to add exception , but that is a separate question). If I reach my site using DNS frontend works, but backend does not work.

Here is unsuccessful with using DNS.
[image]

and successful request using IP address.

[image]

Here is my nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    # include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    upstream backend {
       server api:8000;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/site.org/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/site.org/privkey.pem;

        location /api {

        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                #
                # Om nom nom cookies
                #
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS';
                #
                # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
                #
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
                #
                # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
                #
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
            }
            # Tried this ipv6=off    
            resolver 1.1.1.1 ipv6=off valid=30s;
            set $empty "";
            proxy_pass http://backend$empty;

            # proxy_pass http://backend;

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;

            proxy_http_version  1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_read_timeout 3600;
            proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
            proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;
            proxy_set_header Content-Security-Policy upgrade-insecure-requests;

        }

        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        # location /static/ {
        #     alias /home/app/web/staticfiles/;
        # }
        
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        location / {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
        
        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
           root /var/www/certbot;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add your domain name(s) to the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` list in the `settings.py` Django file?

Comment: That it is. You are correct. Could you add the answer instead of comment, so I could award you with a bounty. It was actually added to ALLOWED_HOSTS previously, but It was added with a protocol (https://) as https://www.example.com. I removed "https://" and left as www.example.com. Now it started to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This HTTP `400 Bad Request` error looks like the one coming from the Django request validation, since your requests differs only by the [`Host`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Host) HTTP request header value. You should include every used domain name to the [`ALLOWED_HOSTS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) list in the `settings.py` Django file. Domain names should be specified as they would appear in the `Host` header (excluding the possible port number); a wildcard-like entry like `.example.com` is allowed, assuming the `example.com` domain and every subdomain. Special value `*` can be used to skip `Host` header validation (not recommended unless you do this validation at some other request processing level).